# How can I include a link in a the popup of a google chrome extension?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am experiencing some problems with a google chrome extension I have made. I've put this simple line of code at the top of the popup page:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
```

However, clicking on it yields no results. But I have someone else's extension that includes links in the popup in exactly the same way, and seems to work. Is there a permissions error of some kind here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Links behave a bit differently in extension popups than they do in ordinary tabs. In a popup, add `target="_blank"` (or an arbitrarily named target) to your anchor tags or use the tab API’s `chrome.tabs.create` method (which will require `tabs` permission in your manifest file).

Comment: FYI, the `tabs` permissions is not required. See [the documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create).